# How to judge whether it is last one in while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach, while-loop

e.g. iOS push program

```
$push = new ApnsPHP();//ApnsPHP push class
/*
  ...
 */

$limit = 1000;

//want not to use fetchAll() method so as to reduce php memory.
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM table');

$i = 0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  $send = true;
  ++$i;
  //adding a que by max $limit count
  $push->add($row['token'],$row['msg']);

  if($i % $limit === 0){
   $push->send();
   $send = false;

  }
}

//send rest que if remaining :#1
if($send){
　$push->send();
}
```

I think doing same thing after while loop is not cool.

So I want to reduce #1 block.

If using fetchAll() and foreach, judgding last one in loop is easy.
But convert tons of all result data to array and keeping is increasing php memory.

Can anyone know cool way?

Sorry for broken English.

Comment: Keeping the resultset into array is common for PHP, you don't need to be frustrated by it

Comment: Thank you.
But in this case, it return thousands  of result set.
Php memory is over. So I can not use fetchAll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, may be it help you:-

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$total_count = $stmt->rowCount();
$i = 0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    $send = true;
    ++$i;
    if($total_count == $i)
    {
        //Do Process For Last Record
    }
    //adding a que by max $limit count
    $push->add($row['token'],$row['msg']);

    if($i % $limit === 0){
        $push->send();
        $send = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you find answer helpful than accept as correct answer, that way this will helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$stmt->rowCount()` to count selected rows.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM table');

$i = 0;
$numRows = $stmt->rowCount();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  $send = true;
  ++$i;

  if($numRows == $i){ 
    echo 'Last iteration';
  }

  //adding a que by max $limit count
  $push->add($row['token'],$row['msg']);

  if($i % $limit === 0){
   $push->send();
   $send = false;

  }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful.Thank you so mach!
I try to use rowCount()